# Navigation Slim Framework project in PHPStorm

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, slim

I'm working on a custom API built with the Slim PHP Framework in PHPStorm 7.

I like how the file structure sidebar works (Navigate>File Structure) but it only lists functions.

Is there a way to list the slim apis get/put calls?

Here's an example of a slim api call.

```
$app->get('/getTest', function () {
    echo ("example test response");
});

$app->put('/putTest', function () {
        echo ("example put response"); 
});
```

Comment: @PranavRam I added an example of the slim framework

Comment: Those are just function/method calls -- they will not be listed in any of the File Structure (be it popup or side panel).

Comment: @LazyOne Exactly, I need a way to be able to browse my project easily. Any suggestions? Is there some type of macro I could type that would appear in the sidebar?

Comment: Nothing ... except writing your own plugin, maybe. My only suggestion (for rather small projects) -- use bookmarks -- may work OK.

Comment: @LazyOne If you write that as the answer I will mark your answer as correct.